# Find the points of contact of the tangent planes to the conicoid 2x^2-25y^2+2z^2=1.

Tags: 3d

Find the points of contact of the tangent planes to the conicoid 2x^2-25y^2+2z^2=1 which pass through the line joining the points (-12,1,12) and (13,-1,-13).I can't understand the meaning of this question ,plese somebody help me to understand this. And solve this question.

Answer (score 1):

[image]. I able to find out ,another image below.

Answer (score 1):

[image]. Is this correct ? Please give your decision.

Comment: If this is correct,then please upvote.